# Inline directories in dired

Tags: dired

In dired, when you use `i` to see the contents of subdirectories, it looks sort of like this:

```
/dir:
file1
subdir1
subdir2

/dir/subdir1:
foo
bar

/dir/subdir2:
baz
```

I want to make it look more like this

```
/dir:
file1
subdir1
  foo
  bar
subdir2
  baz
  bam
```

Is there a way to do that?